# Blank page disappeared between chapters after chapter 2

Tags: page-breaking

I use LaTeX with the document class 'book'. I'd like a blank page between chapters but it works only after chapter 1. I've tried to force a blank page with `\newpage`, `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage` and nothing happens.

How can I add a blank page? Why are they not included automatically after chapters?

Here is my `document.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{./estilos/estiloBase} 
\usepackage{./estilos/colores}  
\usepackage{./estilos/comandos}

\graphicspath{{./imagenes/}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\input{portada.tex}
\cleardoublepage

\input{primerahoja.tex}
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{plain}

\frontmatter 

\input{previo.tex}
\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter 

\chapter{Introducción}
\label{cap:introduccion}
\input{cap1.tex}

\chapter{Descripción general del proyecto}
\label{cap:descripcion}
\input{cap2.tex}

\chapter{Contexto}
\label{cap:contexto}
\input{cap3.tex}
...

\appendix
\cleardoublepage
\addappheadtotoc
\appendixpage
\chapter{Manual de usuario}
\label{cap:manusuario}

\backmatter

\chapter*{Software utilizado}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Software utilizado}
\input{programas.tex}

\cleardoublepage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía y referencias}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliografia}

\input{fdl-1.3.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: An easy option here would be to use `\let\oldchapter\chapter \renewcommand{\chapter}{\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage\oldchapter}` so that the "empty page generation" is incorporated in your `\chapter` command.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick and dirty trick to generate an empty page: including an empty math element:

```
${}$
```

before the `\newpage` command.

Note: there is an entire [site](http://tex.stackexchange.com) devoted to the use of latex, your question might get more attention there.